# Can I create a new Paypal account if I have completely no access to the old one?

Tags: paypal

I need advice: many years ago I created a PayPal account using an email address in the @activist.cc domain.

According to a fellow user here of Super User, the @activist.cc domain used to be owned by www.CommunityMail.net, an ecologist wannabe email provider. But, seems to me that this free email service was disconnected and CommunityMail.net just vanished in the air along with my precious mail. So, I cannot gain access to my PayPal account because, if I choose the "Password forgotten" link, they send a new password to my @activist.cc email address.

Complicating matters, I have also lost my old phone number due. Now I have a new phone number, but, obviously, it is useless for me in recovering my PayPal account, because, they will try to verify my account trough my old and now invalid phone number.

So, as you can see, I am stuck. My sole solution would be, maybe, to try to contact PayPal customer service and try to verify my account trough my physical address and snail mail, which did not change since the creation of my PayPal account. Even so, I remember that the postal codes are changed now and they are different from the postal code it was used at the time when I have created the account.

But, this last solution could last too long and they might consider it unsure from the security point of view. In that case, could I create a whole new PayPal account using my current data?

I know that PayPal doesn't allow this, and that is why I have delayed taking any measure in this direction till now. But now I cannot delay this any more. I want to restart my activity as freelancer and I desperately need an active PayPal account in order to be paid by my partners and employers. And I cannot present in front of them with such lousy excuses as this one related to PayPal. After all, I pretend to be a good PC user. If I cannot solve my PayPal account problem I might look unprofessional, although I am just the victim of certain unfortunate circumstances.

But, beyond my pride is my need. I just need a PayPal account, and I am willing to create a new one if I can, but I must know if this is a safe thing to do and I will not have any bad surprises in the future.

Comment: Having in mind all your existing conditions, it seems contacting Paypal to restore your previous account is the best course of action. Try to explain them what happened in a concise way, they might ask you for data they can check it's yours...
If you had already created a Paypal account previously, then you should be aware of the problems related to it... Unless your concern is about a single person having more than one account...

Comment: My concern is about myself, and I have created only one account till now. Contacting them might be not that easy. I can contact them by mail, of course, but what if I get no replay or they don't understand? In that case I have to contact them by phone? I live in Romania, I don't know exactly when I should call in order to be in the right time. And no, I am not very much aware of the problems related to creating or managing a Paypal account because, as I have told you, I have created it years ago and I have used it just a few times - too rarely to get to know much.

Comment: If, as you say, your snail mail address is the same as it was when you created the account –– and/or if you ever linked a bank account or a credit card to your PayPal account, and you still have access to that –– I agree with the other advice to try to contact PayPal support and tell them what you told us.  Otherwise, it’s probably less hassle to create a new account.

Comment: My snail mail is the same as it was when I have created the account. The only mention is, that the postal code is has been changed till then and I doubt that it is automatically changed somehow in the Paypal data files. But I did not linked my Paypal account to any bank account as I didn't have. I would consider creating a new Paypal account but I don't wont them to believe that I wont to ignore their policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best course of action is to call them. Here's what their web page says -- note the phone number in the upper right for calling from outside the U.S.:

[image: scrrenshot of paypal phone numbers]

Comment: Thank you very much! For whom it may concern: I have just called Paypal and they told me it is OK to create a new Paypal account! I had to call with an + sign in front of the phone number.

Comment: You're welcome. It's good glad to hear you got the situation straightened out.

Comment: Hello! I make this comment during the COVID period. It seems that Paypal has changed their contact details. First of all, the phone contact number is no longer listed on their website although it's still usable. I've called them around 4 AM but the robot answered me telling that they are available 6 AM - 6 PM, Monday to Friday. I don't know if this is a temporary change due to the actuall crisis, or it's a permanent change.